# Which python web frameworks incorporate a web sever that is suitable for production use?

Tags: python, frameworks

I need to write a very light database (sqlite is fine) app that will initially be run locally on a clients windows PC but could, should it ever be necessary, be upgraded to work over the public interwebs without a complete rewrite.

My end user is not very technically inclined and I'd like to keep things as simple as posible. To that end I really want to avoid having to install a local webserver, however "easy" that may seem to you or I. Django specifically warns not to use it's inbuilt webserver in production so my two options seem to be...

a) Use django's built in server anyway while the app is running locally on windows and, if it ever needs to be upgraded to work over the net just stick it behind apache on a linux box somewhere in the cloud.

b) Use a framework that has a more robust built in web server from the start.

My understanding is that the only two disadvantages of django's built in server are a lack of security testing (moot if running only locally) and it's single threaded nature (not likely to be a big deal either for a low/zero concurrency single user app running locally). Am I way off base?

If so, then can I get some other "full stack" framework recommendations please - I strongly prefer python but I'm open to PHP and ruby based solutions too if there's no clear python winner. I'm probably going to have to support this app for a decade or more so I'd rather not use anything too new or esoteric unless it's from developers with some serious pedigree.

Thanks for your advice :)

Roger

Comment: What's wrong with option `(a)`? You wouldn't need to completely rewrite your code if you go this direction.

Comment: Well that's what I was wondering - I'm just new to django (and web frameworks in general) so I thought I'd ask some more experienced peeps.

Comment: I would highly recommend Django. The built-in server is simple to use for development, but it's fairly easy to set up a production server as well. I would be nervous of any framework that attempted to build it's own production-ready Web server from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find Django's admin very easy to use for non-technical clients. In fact, that is the major consideration for my using Django as of late. Once set up properly, non-technical people can very easily update information, which can reflected on the front end immediately.

The client feels empowered.

Comment: You are dead right, I've tried it and it is fantastic! I can see it saving me a truck load of time writing front end interface code which is very happy-making :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Django`. It's very simple for you to get started. Also, they have the best documentation. Follow the step by step app creating tutorial. Django supports all the databases that exist. Also, the built in server is very simple to use for the development and production server. I would highly recommend Django.